# Wake up phone with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, telerik, alarm

I'm trying to create an **hybrid app** that has an built-in alarm, using **Telerik App Builder**, with ***Cordova 3.5***.

I would like to know if is it possible to **wake up** the phone screen when the alarm rings?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, even in native code for iOS at least. The only thing you can do is schedule a local notification.

For Android it might be possible.